# Which JavaScript framework to develop a client-side complex UI? Dojo, SproutCore, Cappuccino

Tags: user-interface, dojo, sproutcore, cappuccino

I have been using Dojo and Dijit for more than a year to develop a browser-based IDE. Dojo is a great framework. But creating an IDE-like interface using Dojo is cumbersome and wastes a lot of time unless you are a CSS superman. I have a good understanding of HTML5, JavaScript, and CSS. Building the UI I needed required several CSS hacking that I found by trial and error. There was no systematic way to get from the UI design to the implementation and I am afraid to change the UI layout because any simple change can break the UI, mostly by adding irrelevant scroll-bars to Dijit panes where I do not need them. (the complex UI has 4-5 levels of nested panes including mostly border containers and content panes)

Recently I have come across SproutCore and Cappuccino, which have great demoes and their look and feel is more desktop-based. There has been several discussions comparing these two with each other. But none of them talk about how systematic and quick is it to get from UI design to implementation? Ideally, I should be able to implement the UI I want not more than a couple of days (Assuming that I know the framework), and changing them in the future should be easy.

The other difficulty with Dojo is that I have to work directly with DOM, to append and remove dijit widgets. While I do like to keep this flexibility, I wish I could use a higher level of abstraction to define the application UI. I have read about MVC in SproutCore and Cappuccino, but I am wondering if in practice the provided abstraction layer speeds up the UI development? or the provided layer is a fancy architecture that only increases the readability of the code? Will I lose the direct access to DOM if I build my UI using these abstractions?

Cheers,
Navid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cappuccino is much higher-level.  You write in Objective-J, not HTML/CSS/JavaScript.  I personally do not recommend it as Objective-J is a niche language and you'd be stuck with something not widely-understood by everybody.  You'll find it more difficult to look for answers to problems, and other people will have more difficulty in maintaining your code.

However, due to it being high level, it does shield you from the drudgery of programming in "standards" (i.e. HTML/CSS/JavaScript).  Therefore, you should be able to develop UI's faster and easier, but you'll have to instead learn the ins-and-outs of Objective-J.  All-in-all, not much to gain here, I suppose.

SproutCore, on the other hand, is HTML/CSS/JavaScript based, so you don't really have to relearn the basics.  It follows the MVC model of separating UI and data concerns, so programming UI's should be easier.

My personal recommendation is to stick with Dojo -- 1.6 has come out, which has change-tracking, state-tracking and bining support.  1.7 is around the corner.  The MVC module is improving fast.  The next version, 2.0, will be quite awesome.  It is being actively developed on, and so you won't be left behind.

Dojo can also be used with the Closure Compiler's *Advanced Mode* to make highly-compact, highly-optimized, fully-obfuscated builds for deployment.  Other JavaScript-based frameworks are not as adaptable.

Answer (score 2):

Cappuccino most definitely goes beyond just improving readability. If you don't want something to have a scrollbar in Cappuccino, don't give it one. That's pretty much the end of the story and one of the great advantages of using such a framework. In my experience, HTML and CSS is just an endless troubleshooting session. With Cappuccino things go where you say they should and stay there. And this is true across browsers as well (most of the time).

Furthermore you can, if you choose to, build your user interface using Interface Builder and Cappuccino's `nib2cib` utility. This makes it trivial both to initially lay out and to then later shuffle buttons and controls around.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered jQuery and the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)?